# What updates the inherited Map of PrefixMap?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Running the PrefixMap example from the book Programming in Scala, 3rd edition, from the chapter The Architecture of Scala Collections, I don't understand what updates the inherited Map of PrefixMap when calling update. 
Here is the code:

```
import collection._

class PrefixMap[T]
  extends mutable.Map[String, T]
    with mutable.MapLike[String, T, PrefixMap[T]] {

  val id: Long = PrefixMap.nextId
  var suffixes: immutable.Map[Char, PrefixMap[T]] = Map.empty
  var value: Option[T] = None

  def get(s: String): Option[T] =
    if (s.isEmpty) value
    else suffixes get s(0) flatMap (_.get(s substring 1))

  def withPrefix(s: String): PrefixMap[T] =
    if (s.isEmpty) this
    else {
      val leading = s(0)
      suffixes get leading match {
        case None =>
          suffixes = suffixes + (leading -> empty)
        case _ =>
      }
      val ret = suffixes(leading) withPrefix (s substring 1)
      println("withPrefix: ends with: id="+this.id+", size="+this.size+", this="+this)
      ret
    }

  override def update(s: String, elem: T) = {
    println("update: this before withPrefix: id="+this.id+", size="+this.size+", return="+this)
    val pm = withPrefix(s)
    println("update: withPrefix returned to update: id="+pm.id+", size="+pm.size+", return="+pm)
    println("===> update: this after withPrefix and before assignment to pm.value : id="+this.id+", size="+this.size+", return="+this)
    pm.value = Some(elem)
    println("===> update: this after assinment to pm.value: id="+this.id+", size="+this.size+", return="+this)
  }

  override def remove(s: String): Option[T] =
    if (s.isEmpty) { val prev = value; value = None; prev }
    else suffixes get s(0) flatMap (_.remove(s substring 1))

  def iterator: Iterator[(String, T)] =
    (for (v <- value.iterator) yield ("", v)) ++
      (for ((chr, m) <- suffixes.iterator;
            (s, v) <- m.iterator) yield (chr +: s, v))

  def += (kv: (String, T)): this.type = { update(kv._1, kv._2); this }

  def -= (s: String): this.type  = { remove(s); this }

  override def empty = new PrefixMap[T]
}

object PrefixMap {
  var ids: Long = 0
  def nextId: Long = { PrefixMap.ids+=1; ids }
}

object MyApp extends App {
  val pm = new PrefixMap[Int]
  pm.update("a", 0)
  println(pm)

}
```

The output is:

update: this before withPrefix: id=1, size=0, return=Map()

withPrefix: ends with: id=1, size=0, this=Map()

update: withPrefix returned to update: id=2, size=0, return=Map()

===> update: this after withPrefix and before assignment to pm.value : id=1, size=0, return=Map()

===> update: this after assinment to pm.value: id=1, size=1, return=Map(a -> 0)

Map(a -> 0)

So the question is: how it is possible that the line with "pm.value = Some(elem)" in the update method causes the inherited Map of PrefixMap to be updated with (a -> 0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what you mean by "***inherited** Map of PrefixMap*". `Map` is a `trait` which if you are coming from the Java world is similar to `interface`. It means that `Map` on its own doesn't hold any value, it just specifies contract and provides some default implementation of various convenience methods via "core" methods (the ones you implement in your `PrefixMap`).

As to how this whole data structure works, you should imagine this `PrefixMap` implementation as a ["tree"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)). Logically each edge has a single char (in the prefix sequence) and each node potentially a value that corresponds to a string that is created by accumulation all chars on the way from the root to the current node.

So if you have a Map with `"ab" -> 12` key-value, the tree will look something like this:
[image: ab tree]

And if you add `"ac" -> 123` to the tree, it will become

[image: ab+ac tree]

Finally if you add `"a" -> 1` to the tree, it will become:

[image: a+ab+ac tree]

Important observation here is that if you take the "a" node as a root, what you'll be left with is a valid prefix tree with all strings shortened by that "a" prefix.

Physically the layout is a bit different:

1. There is the root node which is `PrefixMap[T]` which is `Map[String,T]` from the outside, and also a node for an empty string key.
2. Internal nodes which are `value` + `suffixes` i.e. optional value and merged list of children nodes with their corresponding characters on the edge into a `Map[Char, PrefixMap[T]]`

As you may see `update` implementation is effectively find something with `withPrefix` call and then assigning value to it. So what the `withPrefix` method does? Although it is implemented recursively, it might be easier to think about it in an iterative way. From this point of view, it iterates over the characters of the given `String` one by one and navigates through the tree creating missing nodes see

```scala
 case None =>
      suffixes = suffixes + (leading -> empty)
```

and finally returns the node corresponding to the whole `String` (i.e. `this` in case the deepest recursive `s.isEmpty`)

Method `get` implementation is actually quite similar to the `withPrefix`: it recursively iterates over given string and navigates through the tree but it is simpler because it doesn't have to create missing nodes. Because children nodes are actually also stored in a `Map` its `get` method returns `Option` the same way `PrefixMap` should return `Option`. So you can just use `flatMap` and it will work OK if there is no such child node at some level.

Finally `iterator` creates its iterator as a union of

1. the `value.iterator` (luckily `Option` in Scala implements `iterator` that returns just 1 or 0 elements depending on whether there is a value or not)
2. all `iterator`s of all the children nodes just adding its own character as a prefix to their keys.

So when you do

```
val pm = new PrefixMap[Int]
pm.update("a", 0)
println(pm)
```

`update` creates are node(s) in the tree and stores the value. And `pm.toString` actually uses `iterate` to build string representation. So it iterates over the tree collection all the values in non-empty `value` `Option`s in all the nodes.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks.
By "inherited Map of PrefixMap" I meant the PrefixMap as a Map by itself, in contrast to to the Map it references (suffixes).
What I mainly missed is understanding the iteraror implementation, and that's why I was surprised that simple value assignment made key value mapping in the PrefixMap. 
Thanks for your clear explanation!